# Рефакторинг программы

Tags: c#, wpf, инспекция-кода

Я написал программу,которая рандомным образом выбирает глагол на русском языке из текстового документа и показывает нам его. Задача пользователя состоит в том,что он должен ввести в текстбоксы этот же глагол в 1,2,3 формах английского языка.
Собственно сам код:

```
namespace Verbs2
{
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        int randomNum = 0;
        int counterWin = 0;
        int counterLose = 0;
        bool ifChecked = false;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public class Verbs
        {

            /*класс создан для работы над глаголами и текстового файла*/

            string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Рустем\Desktop\проекты\Verbs2\Verbs2\verbs.txt",
                System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));//считываем все строки в массив
            List<string[]> res = new List<string[]>();
            public Verbs()
            {
                foreach (var line in readText)//перебираем строки массива
                {
                    res.Add(line.Split('.'));//Каждую строку сплитим и помещаем в список массивов.
                }
            }
            public string GetVerb(int a)//метод позволяет достать из листа глагол на русском языке(в 3 столбце находятся русские глаголы)
            {
                return res[a][3];
            }
            public string GetVerb(int a, int b)
            {
                return res[a][b];
            }
            public bool CheckVerbs(string a, string b, string c, int d)//проверяем соответствуют ли введенные данные,той строке что мы выбрали
            {
                if ((a.Equals(res[d][0])) && (b.Equals(res[d][1])) && (c.Equals(res[d][2])))
                    return true;
                else return false;
            }
        }

        public void SetRandom()
        {
            /*в нашем текстовом документе 68 глаголов,поэтому мы выбираем один рандомный глагол из 68*/
            Random rnd = new Random();
            randomNum = rnd.Next(0, 68);
        }

        public int GetRandom()
        {
            return randomNum;
        }

        private void btnstart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            /*при нажатии на кнопку "начать" создаем объект класса verb, выбираем рандомной глагол, вставляем его в lblverb2 и делаем доступной кнопку btncheck*/
            Verbs verb = new Verbs();
            SetRandom();
            lblverb2.Content = verb.GetVerb(GetRandom());
            btncheck.IsEnabled = true;
            counterWin = 0;
            counterLose = 0;
        }

        private void btncheck_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            /* в лэйблы 4-6 вставляем глаголы на английском языке
             проверяем соответсвуют ли введенные в текстбоксы глаголы,выбранному глаголу
             делаем доступной кнопку btnnext*/
            Verbs verb = new Verbs();
            lblverb4.Content = verb.GetVerb(GetRandom(), 0);
            lblverb5.Content = verb.GetVerb(GetRandom(), 1);
            lblverb6.Content = verb.GetVerb(GetRandom(), 2);
            if (verb.CheckVerbs(textverb1.Text, textverb2.Text, textverb3.Text, GetRandom()))
            {
                lborder.BorderBrush = Brushes.Green;
                counterWin++;
                lblcw.Content = counterWin.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lborder.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
                counterLose++;
                lblcl.Content = counterLose.ToString();
            }
            btnnext.IsEnabled = true;
            btncheck.IsEnabled = false;
            ifChecked = true;
        }

        private void btnnext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            /*по сути повторяет действия кнопки btnstart,но при этом очищает лэйблы и текстбоксы*/
            Verbs verb = new Verbs();
            SetRandom();
            lblverb2.Content = verb.GetVerb(GetRandom());
            btncheck.IsEnabled = true;
            if (ifChecked == false)
                counterLose++;
            lblcl.Content = counterLose.ToString();
            ifChecked = false;
            lblverb4.Content = "";
            lblverb5.Content = "";
            lblverb6.Content = "";
            textverb1.Text = "";
            textverb2.Text = "";
            textverb3.Text = "";
            lborder.BorderBrush = Brushes.White;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: интерфейс программы]

Код XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Verbs2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Неправильные глаголы" Height="350" Width="360">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="52*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="24*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="24*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--меню-->
        <Menu  Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="White">
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="New Project" ></MenuItem>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="Exit" ></MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>

        <!---->
        <Label x:Name="lblverb1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">Глагол:</Label>
         <Label x:Name="lblverb2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"></Label>
        <Label x:Name="lblverb3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">Счетчик</Label>

        <!--лейблы для глаголов на английском языке-->
        <Label x:Name="lblverb4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"></Label>
        <Label x:Name="lblverb5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"></Label>
        <Label x:Name="lblverb6" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"></Label>
        <!--лейблы для набора текста пользователем -->
        <TextBox x:Name="textverb1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textverb2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textverb3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"></TextBox>

        <Button x:Name="btnstart" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Click="btnstart_Click">Начать</Button>
        <Button x:Name="btncheck"  IsEnabled="False" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Click="btncheck_Click">Проверить</Button>
        <Button x:Name="btnnext"  IsEnabled="False" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Click="btnnext_Click">Следующий</Button>


        <Label x:Name="lblcw" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1">0</Label>
        <Label x:Name="lbllblslash" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1">/</Label>
        <Label x:Name="lblcl" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1">0</Label>

        <Border x:Name="lborder" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="360" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"/>
        <Border x:Name="lborder1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="74" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="352" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"/>
        <Border x:Name="lborder2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"  Height="71" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Width="352" Margin="0,0,0.444,0"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Хотелось бы провести рефакторинг кода. Что в нем можно улучшить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем с самого основного - класса. Вместо использования двумерного массива, лучше вынести логику работы с глаголом в отдельный класс, например:

```
public class Verb
{
    public string Rus { get; set; }
    public string F1 { get; set; }
    public string F2 { get; set; }
    public string F3 { get; set; }
}
```

*названия свойство можно и более содержательные придумать =)*

Хранить элементы можно в обычном массиве:

```
    Verb[] data;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        data =
            File.ReadLines("data.txt")
            .Select(x => x.Split('.'))
            .Select(x => new Verb { F1 = x[0], F2 = x[1], F3 = x[2], Rus = x[3] })
            .ToArray();
    }
```

Обратите внимание на использование относительного пути, вместо абсолютного.
Вместо разбора строки можно использовать десериализацию в удобный формат.

Методы `GetRandom()` И `SetRandom` избыточны. Кроме этого вы жестко задаете верхнюю границу. Можно использовать свойство .Length:

```
    Verb current;
    private void setNextVerb()
    {
        current = data[rnd.Next(data.Length)];
    }

    private void btnstart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        setNextVerb();
        btncheck.IsEnabled = true;
        counterWin = 0;
        counterLose = 0;
    }
```

На мой взгляд эта кнопка вообще не нужна и такой код лучше поместить, например, в конструктор.

В методе `CheckVerbs` вы используете конструкцию вида:

```
if something return true; else return false;
```

которая может быть сведена к

```
return something;
```

То есть можно написать сразу так:

```
    //проверяем соответствуют ли введенные данные,той строке что мы выбрали
    private bool CheckVerbs(string a, string b, string c, Verb verb)
    {
        return a.Equals(verb.F1) && b.Equals(verb.F2) && c.Equals(verb.F3);
    }
```

Тогда ваши обработчики изменятся следующим образом:

```
   private void btncheck_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblverb4.Content = current.F1;
        lblverb5.Content = current.F2;
        lblverb6.Content = current.F3;
        if (CheckVerbs(textverb1.Text, textverb2.Text, textverb3.Text, current))
        { ...
```

и

```
    private void btnnext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        setNextVerb();
        lblverb2.Content = current.Rus;
```

---

Что касается XAML разметки - она не гибкая. Попробуйте изменять размер окна и вы поймете о чем идет речь.
При первой возможности напишу об этом подробнее.

---

Лучшее решение - переписать код через `MVVM`. Не хочу приводить здесь такой вариант, так как будет намного лучше, если вы сделаете это самостоятельно.

Comment: Спасибо, что так подробно все расписали. Не переписывая код через MVVM, это все что можно улучшить?

Comment: @Draktharon извините, что долго не отвечал. Не было возможности. В переходе на `MVVM` нет ничего сложного. Если хотите можем сделать это поэтапно. Для более быстрого и удобного общения предлагаю перейти в [чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--)

Answer (score 3):

1)В кнопках много логики.

Кнопки должны содержать минимум логики и по возможности дергать 1 метод, где и будет описана вся логика.

2)Почему бы не создать отдельный класс, который будет содержать 4 поля: Русский глагол, 1-форма, 2-форма,3- форма? Затем, этот класс оборачиваешь в еще 1 класс, и хранишь все в List и делаешь методы сравнения и т п.
Этим ты заменишь работу с массивом в Verbs. Ты сможешь работать с конкретными полями, а не рукоблудить индексы двумерного массива.

3)Возможно, имеет смысл хранить глаголы не в TXT файле, а в XML и выполнять десериализацию.(Особенное, если будешь следовать совету 2).

Answer (score 1):

Вот это очень плохо, т.к. путь к файлу прибит к вашему рабочему каталогу

```
 string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Рустем\Desktop\проекты\Verbs2\Verbs2\verbs.txt",
            System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
```

Да, и зачем кодировка 1251. У вас что, работа в Windows XP планируется? Все ж давно на юникод перешли!

Создайте папку в вашем проекте `Assets`, затем прав.клав.клик по этой папке Add->Existing Item->и укажите ваш `verbs.txt` установите у него свойства Build Action в Embedded Resource. А далее его можно будет прочитать так (пример из моего проекта = читаю список стран)

```
StrList = new List<string>();
using (Stream stream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WpfEmbeddedResource.Assets.Countries.txt"))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string input = null;
    while ((input = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        StrList.Add(input);
    }
}
```

`WpfEmbeddedResource` - это название проекта.